# Posting to PAGE as PAGE

Tags: oauth, facebook-php-sdk, access-token, user-permissions

I am trying to automate posting (in PHP) to a Facebook Page, as the Facebook Page. I am having issues with getting a non-expiring token, and then posting as the page. It seems I can post as user with the non-expiring token, but not as page. As the documentation leaves a lot to be desired in the way of examples, could someone outline the steps to make this happen? I have created an app, and granted manage_pages, publish_stream and offline_access permissions from user. When I try to post to page (no problem), it posts as user, not page. I am struggling with the concept with un-expiring access tokens for user vs un-expiring tokens for the page.

Code to give permissions:

```
<?
require_once 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

if(is_null($facebook->getUser()))
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,manage_pages,offline_access'))}");
 exit;
}
?>
```

and code to make post:

```
<?
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "APP_ID";
$app_secret = "APP_SECRET";
$page_id = "PAGE_ID";
$page_access_token = "PAGE_TOKEN";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

if( !empty($page_access_token) ) {
    $args = array(
        'access_token'  => $page_access_token,
        'message'       => "Test post"
    );
    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$page_id/feed","post",$args);
} else {
}
header("Location: http://example.com/")

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Pages (/me/accounts) access_token Expiration?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9235695/facebook-pages-me-accounts-access-token-expiration)

Answer (score 1):

Did you know that [offline_access](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/) is deprecated?

Comment: I didn't see that...thanks. So, I guess to autopost to a page as a page, one would have to get a new token each time (or exchange token) ? Any sample?

Answer (score 0):

just created a brand new app. Ensured the deprecate offline access was enabled. Went to explorer, found my new app in the drop-down, granted myself `manage_pages`, went to `me/accounts` grabbed one of the page access tokens, and then linted it.Bummer, 1 hour expiration, so that's not good. So I tried *exchanging* that 1 hour page token and I got an error from Facebook.

I went back to the user access token, and exchanged it for a 60 day one. Verified in the linter that it was a 60 day. Went back to `me/accounts` and grabbed one of the page access tokens and linted it. Surprise! Got a 60 day token from there.

So the moral of the story is, you cannot exchange page tokens, only user tokens. But with a 60 day user token you can get a 60 day page token. :)